# Aligning images with a tabular environment

Tags: tables, beamer, graphics, alignment

I'm trying to align my [images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taraxacum) in a tabular environment like so:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}                                                                                                                                 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{Aligning images with a tabular environment}

  \centering

  \begin{tabular}{|c | c |}
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{img/440px-DandelionFlower} &
    \multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{img/440px-Blackwell_dens_leonis}}\\
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{img/440px-TaraxacumOfficinaleSeed} & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But as you can see in the output, one image seems shifted off from the table. How can I get the image to fit within its cell?
[image: Output]

Comment: Try loading `adjustbox` with option `[export]` and use `\includegraphics[width=2cm, valign=c]{...dens_leonis}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with help of the`adjustbox` and option `[t]` at `multrow` cell:

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{Aligning images with a tabular environment}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{|c | c |}
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,
                     valign=t, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{img/440px-DandelionFlower}
        &   \multirow[t]{2}{*}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=4.2cm,
                            valign=t, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{img/440px-Blackwell_dens_leonis}}\\
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,
                     valign=t, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{img/440px-TaraxacumOfficinaleSeed}
        &   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
```